# Finding and running FindSQLInstall.vbs script file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the problem and I'm trying to resolve it by following this link

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/969052

However, when it says

"To complete the steps in this procedure, you have to copy the FindSQLInstalls.vbs script from the "More Information" section to a local folder on the computer where you are trying to update your SQL Server installation."

I'm confused on how to find this "FindSQLInstall.vbs" file and how to run it.

I'm just a beginner, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The FindSQLInstall.vbs file is attached below in the link itself. https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/969052#bookmark-script. Use the command `Cscript FindSQLInstalls.vbs %computername%_sql_install_details.txt` by opening your cmd in the folder same folder where you are saving the above file.

Comment: @AkashAmin But all I can see right now is the code and no download link, do I need copy the code to some file and save it ?

Comment: Yes..do the same as mentioned there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this error while trying to put SP3 on SQL 2008 R2.  Some research lead me to the same article https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/969052 and the FindSQLInstall.vbs Script.

I also do not have a lot of experience with command prompt or .vbs  I do have some coworkers who have previously worked through the same issue.  If you have found the Microsofts kb/969052, in theory everything you need is there.  But if you are like me you need a bit more. This is what I did.

Note that I was **VERY** Lucky, We have a share folder where we keep copies of all of the upgrade/updates that we install.  The .vbs found and copied many of my missing things (*though it took me a while to figure that out*)

- Create folder on the server for working on issue 'C:\Repair_msi' = This puts all my housekeeping in one place
- Save FindSQLInstalls.vbs script from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969052#bookmark-script in this folder

  - Create text doc, paste in the script and rename as 'FindSQLInstalls.vbs' you will probably need to show hidden extensions to convert from .txt > .vbs
- In command prompt type `cd C:\Repair_msi` = cmd working in this folder
- In command prompt type `Cscript FindSQLInstalls.vbs ServerName_sql_install_details.txt`
- Open the new document 'ServerName_sql_install_details.txt' which is now in this folder
- The document says the .vbs found and copied over several missing .msi files

  - Missing cache file replaced by copying....
  - Previously missing package C:\Windows\Installer\67fe40cc.msi now exists in the Installer cache.
  - Validated that .msi files that were reported as missing on first error, have been identified by the .vbs and are now in C:\Windows\Installer
  - DOES NOT exist, directions do occur, called out with

> - !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
> - !!!! C:\Windows\Installer\4541a.msi DOES NOT exist in the Installer cache. !!!!
> - !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

- The path called out in action plan is temp folder on the PC of a coworker who did a previous install, no hope of recovery from there.
- No action taken
- Rename 'ServerName_sql_install_details.txt' > '1-ServerName_sql_install_details.txt'
- In command prompt type `Cscript FindSQLInstalls.vbs ServerName_sql_install_details.txt` = Run the .vbs again
- Open the new document 'ServerName_sql_install_details.txt' which is now in this folder

  - New document is essentially the same as old, except it now says the previously missing .msi are now present and gives some direction if you still get errors on update
  - The 'DOES NOT exist' item still exists.  I used crtl+F to search the document and this is the only required thing listed.

    > Copy "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\LWRNT0CZ\SQLServer2005_BC[1].msi" C:\Windows\Installer\4541a.msi
  - We have a folder with pretty much every SQL install and upgrade, on searching I find multiple SQLServer2005_BC.msi but no 4541a.msi
  - More reading and I learn that we need to find the **correct version** of SQLServer2005_BC.msi; copy and rename it to 4541a.msi
  - Can't find version numbers for the 30+ versions we have on the share....
- Maybe we don't really need that one?
- Try the SP install, It does not error out, I get to the Install now step (first attempt errored very early)
- Pending off hours time slot to apply SP to this production server

### In summary

It turns out I could have just run the FindSQLInstalls.vbs Script and then run the SP install again. The .vbs will return results which include the place the file was when it was last used as well as the version number.  If the .vbs does not find it there, you will need to find what it wants, copy it and rename it with the correct name and put it the correct place.